# draw contours in Android using opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I have code in Android which processes an image and returns a binary image.

```
  Imgproc.cvtColor(source, middle, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Mat element  = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(15, 15), new Point(0, 0));
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(middle, middle, MORPH_TOPHAT, element, new Point(0, 0));
    Imgproc.threshold(middle, middle, 20, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

[image]

[[image]][2

Now, my requirement is, that instead of binary image i need to highlight the dents on the original image. Like this:

[image]

What I figured out is to use

```
   Core.findnonzero()
```

to get the coordinates of the dents and then use drawcontours on the original image.This is just an idea.

My questions are:
1. What is the best way to do it?
2. what is matofpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findContours()` function of OpenCV on the binary image (`middle` as in your code) and then iterate on all over the top level contours in the list and draw them on the original (source) image, just something like this:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(middle, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// now iterate over all top level contours
for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = (int) hierarchy.get(0, idx)[0]) {
    MatOfPoint matOfPoint = contours.get(idx);
    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(matOfPoint);
    Imgproc.rectangle(originalImage, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255));
}
```